# Show more/less text in a table automatically according to text length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have a table with two columns, the second one sometimes contains big text so I want to show only the first 100 characters and put a show more link to display the remaining text. You can see here what Table I am working on http://jsfiddle.net/j11mj21x/.

For that I am using a code provided in this link (http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/), I put it in a file show_less_more.js :

```
 (function($) {
$.fn.shorten = function (settings) {

    var config = {
        showChars: 100,
        ellipsesText: "...",
        moreText: "more",
        lessText: "less"
    };

    if (settings) {
        $.extend(config, settings);
    }

    $(document).off("click", '.morelink');

    $(document).on({click: function () {

            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass('less')) {
                $this.removeClass('less');
                $this.html(config.moreText);
            } else {
                $this.addClass('less');
                $this.html(config.lessText);
            }
            $this.parent().prev().toggle();
            $this.prev().toggle();
            return false;
        }
    }, '.morelink');

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass("shortened")) return;

        $this.addClass("shortened");
        var content = $this.html();
        if (content.length > config.showChars) {
            var c = content.substr(0, config.showChars);
            var h = content.substr(config.showChars, content.length - config.showChars);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + config.ellipsesText + ' </span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span> <a href="#" class="morelink">' + config.moreText + '</a></span>';
            $this.html(html);
            $(".morecontent span").hide();
        }
    });

};

})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function(){$(".descriptionText").shorten();});
```

I am using it like this:

```
    <script src="show_less_more.js"></script>"
```

The HTML is like this for every row:

```
    <tr>
      <th>
        course1
      </th>
      <td> <div class="descriptionText">Description of the course</div></td>
    </tr>
```

I have also added the CSS for the more and less links:

```
        a {
        color: #0254EB
        }
        a:visited {
        color: #0254EB
        }
        a.morelink {
        text-decoration:none;
        outline: none;
        }
        .morecontent span {
        display: none;
        }
```

When I do this in sfiddle it works pretty good as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/j11mj21x/2/
However, I get nothing when rendering my table with python. 
I think the problem is that I don't succeed to load my JS page into the html page, because when I click on it it give nothing.
Here is what is rendered in my html page:

```
 ....
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"><!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript --><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script><script src="showLessMore.js"></script>
....
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem behind this because I have the "show_less_more.js" in the same folder as the file generator which in python?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You can make it easier to help by setting up this function in jsfiddle. I see you did that on the table you want to apply this to, but it doesn't include any of the functionality you are asking for help with. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks... that is odd. It works fine with just the HTML, and I see how you have set up the events on document.click with child target to support dynamically added elements.

Comment: What if you try just on document.click? Pass in the event, and check if event.currentTarget.hasClass('more') ..... does that solve it?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the way I am using the javascript file in which there are my JS functions. Because when I click on it to see what is inside I don't get the file even though the file is in the same folder as the web page

Comment: Just put some console logs in that file then and see if you see them in the web inspector.

Comment: When I try to download the JS where my functions are it doesn't load. In fact I am doing the same as for my CDNs. However, It doesn't work. When I just do like this to see if the file is there I get nothing http://localhost:9000/showLessMore.js I get my page instead

Comment: I've resolved the problem by put the code directly into the page without using the external file. It is bizarre but at least it works now ! Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of doing this relying more on CSS.

```js
$(function() {

  $('a').click(function() {
    $('div').removeClass('ellipsis');
  });
  
});
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px orange;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ellipsis'>Some really really long text that just is way too long so we must use ellipses to shorten it until the user wants to see it all.</div>
<br>
<a href='#'>Show All</a>
```

Comment: Than you for your response, but my code normally works as showed in the demo. However, I find that my JS file is not loaded I don't know if there is a problem with the way I am loading the script into my page ? Thank you in advance !