# Find length of string without counting included html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a paragraph which has HTML tags in it. I need to restrict it to 100 characters after the parse of HTML. For example

```html
Hello<a href ="#"> World </a>
```

If my length check is for 8, then my HTML should be `Hello Wo` where `Wo` should be an anchor tag. There can be any other tags. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what if you have already more than _<limit>_ characters before your link?

Comment: Maybe this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript might help. It talks about how to remove HTML from a text, so you can count the other characters

Comment: break there it self, in the above example if the limit is 5, the output would be "hello"

Comment: so your link would be compromised but you asked to not lose elements.

Comment: Actually, the paragraph will be followed by show more and show less link, where i  ll be showing the whole thing again.

Comment: @Sorix, Thanks for the suggestion, but my requirement is bit different. I could learn something from the link u shared, thanks

Comment: If show less or more is your purpose there are easier ways to achieve that [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735726/show-more-less-text-with-just-html-and-javascript), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653528/show-more-less-text-in-a-table-automatically-according-to-text-length). Maybe not exactly of 100 characters but with pixels or something else

Comment: sir, The link will shown after certain length check. Hello Wo then the anchor tag of show more

Answer (score 5):

You can use a REGEX expresion when getting the innerHTML

Then count the characters.

Example:

```js
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    var body = 'Hello<a href ="#"> World </a>';
    var result = body.replace(regex, "");
    
    console.log(result + ' ' + result.length);
```

Comment: Thanks, where do i pass the length.

Comment: Use the result.length in your validating function

Comment: This will work great until you run into an attribute containing either the "<" or ">" characters...

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var $html=$('<span></span>');
$html.append('Hello<a href ="#"> World </a>');
var text=$html.text();
console.log("Text :: "+text);
console.log("Length :: "+text.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using this way you can create html elment virtually then `text()` will parse the text content from html.